# How Many Endings Does Breath of the Wild Have?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Players have taken many different paths on their way to defeating the game's final boss. Are there different endings that reflect your choices throughout the game?

I've heard of "secret" endings, an ending with Epona, and endings unlocked only by full completion of everything else in the game. On the other hand, I heard that there are only two endings to the game. I haven't beaten the game yet, but I'd like to know so I can decide what to accomplish in game before I attempt to defeat Calamity Ganon.

**I will accept the answer which clearly lays out *how many endings the game has*, and *what conditions are required to unlock them*.**

Comment: I've explained what I've read on the subject and explained why I'm asking it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 2 currently confirmed [endings](http://twinfinite.net/2017/03/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-endings-how-to-get/) to Breath of the Wild:

**1) Basic Ending:**

This is the easier of the two endings, and is achieved upon defeating Ganon's true form, without having completed all of the side-missions and extras throughout the game.

What happens:

> Zelda appears, and seals the evil away. Before the credits, Zelda asks Link if he truly remembers her. the credits then roll.

You can watch the Basic Ending [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5sdgel6i6g).

**2) True Ending**

This ending is unlocked by collecting all 18 of [Link's memories](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Memories).

What happens:

> It is caled the "True Ending" because the basic ending is an "incomplete" version of this ending. After the credits roll and shows Link and Zelda together again, in their Hylian garb, looking upon a Hyrule that’s full of life and devoid of any evil forces. Zelda’s work isn’t done though. She’s going to work to keep the peace and make sure that everyone’s prepared for the next time Ganon decides to show up. She’s rebuilding the kingdom and ensuring that nothing so horrible ever happens again. And she intends to do all of this without her powers which have gone dormant after Ganon was sealed. She smiles, content with her being without any extra abilities as she and Link set out to ride their horses to the Zora Domain to take care of Divine Beast Vah Ruta.

You can watch the True Ending [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb9nBCI5Gis).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Great answer!