# Quests or events with multiple permanent end states

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

On the Isolated Plateau, you can aquire a Warm Doublet from the Old Man. As far as I know, there are three ways to get it:

> 1. Cook him the dish he hints at in his diary.

Or

> 2. Meet him up at the top of the mountain on the plateau.

Or

> 3. Complete all four shrines on the plateau, and it'll be waiting in a chest in the Old Man's hut.

Each option ends with a different entry in the Old Man's diary. After one of the three options is complete, the others become unavailable.

Are there other quests or events such as this, with multiple permanent "end states"? Different entries in the adventure log, different diary entries, or different relationships to NPCs, things like that. If the results are going to be permanent, I'd like to plan out how I approach these, to get the result I prefer.

Transient things like a bit of non-repeated dialogue or a replaceable item reward are less important, because they don't permanently affect the world.

And I'm aware that playing the game naturally without worrying about such minor things would be more enjoyable. However finding out 20 hours later that there was a better ending to a quest that I cannot now replicate tends to sap my enjoyment too.

Comment: Just don't look up spoilers.  There's logically no way for you to know about these end states unless you look then up.  Look it up after you beat the game.

Answer (score 2):

All of these outcomes have no effect on how NPCs interact with you. Once the mission ends, they will react to you in the same way they would have regardless, so these "outcomes" are merely aesthetic, and temporary.

The only mission that *does* have an effect on the game, is the [Locked Mementos](http://au.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Locked_Mementos) main questline, which unlocks the [True Ending](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310180/how-many-endings-does-breath-of-the-wild-have) of the game.

Comment: These small aesthetic changes are exactly what I'm referring to. The Warm Doublet is just the first, and so far only, example I'm aware of. My question is, are there others? Even if they have no effect on the main quest, I might still prefer to approach them differently.